Whats wrong with concept of "faster than light" information transfer device? (not about technical implementation, just about theory)
Yesterday, while lying in bed, an idea came to me, and I don’t understand why it won’t work?

Setup:
1.1) Two infinite stores of entangled pairs of photons, each connected to a double-slit device.
1.2) Each of them can emit photons in the same order.
1.3) The devices are separated by a vast distance (1B light years, as example).

Modulation:
One device modulates a binary signal by toggling the detector on/off, influencing whether an interference pattern appears (wave-like behavior) or disappears (particle-like behavior).

Observation:
At the distant device, a screen and macro-sensor (like a camera) are used to detect changes in the interference pattern to (particle-like and back to wave-like behavior). These changes are interpreted as the binary signal.


What's wrong with this concept?

Please use the search function: Questions like this have been asked here before several times.

Does this answer your question? Why is quantum entanglement considered to be an active link between particles?

I disagree with the reason given for closing the question. I think there are some reasons the question could be closed (its not really precise enough to answer properly, and there might exist a duplicate somewhere) but this is clearly a question about quantum mechanics, not some "unpublished personal theory".

Please open a question, cause this question is about quantum mechanics, it's not any kind of "unpublished personal theory". It's directly about "mainstream physics".

FWIW: Closing* one slit in a double-slit apparatus does not cause the photons to start "behaving like particles." Light passing through a narrow slit is diffracted, and diffraction is wave-like behavior. With only one slit open, the waves make a single-slit diffraction pattern. With two-slits open, you get interference between the waves emanating from both slits, and you get a different pattern. But, either case is fully explained by the wave-like behavior of light.

* I'm not going to pretend to understand the difference between physically closing one slit and "detecting which slit..."

"Particle-like" behavior enters into the picture when you attenuate the light source to the point where, practically, there is never more than one photon in-flight in the experiment at any given moment in time. If you do that, and if the detector "screen" actually is a electronic image sensor, then you can count each photon as it arrives, and you can locate where it interacted with the sensor. Being able to count and locate the interactions is the observable, "particle-like" behavior.

Good idea, but one minor problem: Entangled particles do not form standard single particle interference patterns in the first place, so Alice's actions will not change anything for Bob. The full reasons are outside the context of the OP, but the short version is that entangled particles are not coherent. See for example Zeilinger (1999) Experiment and the foundations of quantum physics. Figure 2 discusses this exact situation. https://courses.washington.edu/ega/more_papers/zeilinger.pdf

Please read https://ar5iv.org/abs/1304.4943 (Piotr Kolenderski, Carmelo Scarcella 2013)  When measurements are made on one of the entangled particles, the state of its partner is instantaneously influenced, resulting in consistent patterns on both screens.

@SolomonSlow What are you talk about?  I not say about "closing or open", I telling about collapsing wave function one of photons and detect wave function is collapsed or not on the other one by reading screen pattern. It requires BIG amount of particles and synchronized emit. But all of that is the practical issues, not theoretical.

"Collapsing the wave function" does not mean that the photon was cruising along, acting like a wave, when you suddenly strip it of its wave function, and cause it to have to behave like a particle from that point on. There is always a wave function that represents all of the possible outcomes of the experiment. If you can "collapse" it without destroying the photon, then that means you have gained information—you have eliminated all but one of the possibilities in that exact moment—and from then on, there is a new wave function describing the photon's future.

Re, "...closing one slit..." I'm going out on a limb here, but I'm pretty sure that a photon's behavior doesn't depend on whether or not you are watching to see where it went. It's the configuration of the experiment that determines how the photons will behave. In any double-slit experiment whose configuration makes it possible to acquire knowledge of "which slit," each photon must behave as if the slit that it went through was the only slit. So, I'm suggesting that you can understand how the photons behave in the "which way" experiment by understanding how they behave with a single-slit.

Please read my response to your comment below ors' answer, and please use my link to the paper instead of yours: https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.4943 You are correct in one sense: the patterns are always consistent on both screens. That is 100% correct theory. However, theory also says that it is the ENTIRE context that dictates the results, i.e. the measurement settings on BOTH sides. Further, order of measurement is NOT a factor. You cannot say Alice's earlier DS measurement influences Bob's later results than vice versa, which becomes obvious the in hundreds of delayed choice experiments.

@SolomonSlow You are correct that it is the possibility of acquiring which slit information that is critical. You cannot see this on one side using entangled photons, since they are not coherent and don't generate the usual DS interference pattern. But it is possible to obtain which slit information for non-entangled photons without blocking a slit - and the interference pattern disappears when you do that. See https://sciencedemonstrations.fas.harvard.edu/files/science-demonstrations/files/single_photon_paper.pdf

@DrChinese Abstract logic is very the simple:  1) You have pattern correlation on both screens (proof https://www.nature.com/articles/srep04685)   2) You can synchronized order of emit   3) COMMUNICATION PROFIT   Please stop send me links to non-communication theorem, this device is not disprove the theorem.

@NikolayPrays I didn’t send/say anything about the No Communication theorem. Your idea is specifically disproved by experiment in the Nature article you cited. See figure 4(a), the gold line with triangles labeled “D1 or D2”. It shows what an observer on one side sees: no interference pattern. Such pattern appears only when coincidence matching (heralding) is performed with the other. That requires classical communication (i.e. not FTL). My point is that you have misread the paper, which proves conclusively that entangled photons do not alone produce the usually expected Double Slit pattern.

There isn't enough information given here to answer this question fully, but the short version is that whatever you do at you do for the "modulation" has absolutely no observable effect on anything you can detect at the distant device.
The formal reason for this is the no-communication theorem, which you can read more about on wikipedia, or many other places

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
